# How do i fix npm run start?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I'm using react and I'm trying to run my app
When I run "npm run start" it shows this error

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-18T23_55_28_093Z-debug-0.log
```

In the debug log it shows this:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.19.1
2 info using node@v19.8.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Bruger\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 12ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm start
22 verbose argv "start"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
27 verbose logfile C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-18T23_55_28_093Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 24ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing command:run-script Completed in 8ms
35 timing command:start Completed in 13ms
36 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "start"
36 verbose stack
36 verbose stack Did you mean one of these?
36 verbose stack     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
36 verbose stack     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
36 verbose stack
36 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
36 verbose stack   npm run
36 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\run-script.js:98:13)
36 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
37 verbose cwd C:\Users\Bruger\Downloads\landrup-dans-api-main
38 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
39 verbose node v19.8.1
40 verbose npm  v8.19.1
41 error Missing script: "start"
41 error
41 error Did you mean one of these?
41 error     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
41 error     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
41 error
41 error To see a list of scripts, run:
41 error   npm run
42 verbose exit 1
43 timing npm Completed in 51ms
44 verbose code 1
45 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
45 error     C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-18T23_55_28_093Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Can you share the "scripts" block of your package.json?

Comment: share the scripts object in you package.json file

Comment: if you are using CRA create react app use npm start and if you are using vite use npm run dev

Comment: It wont let me post my edit of package.json, it comes up with 
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: You can remove the second snippet of the debug log as it's not adding more information about your error. Also, explain how you installed CRA? Can you run other scripts? Are you running npm start from the same directory as your package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen when you run `npm start` in a directory that has a `package.json` file that does not have a script called `start` in `"scripts"` block.

Please check that you are in the correct path with:

```bash
pwd # or "cd" for windows
```

You are in the correct path, try running `npm run` and see if your scripts are there, you should see something like:

```
  start
    node index.js
  test
    jest
```

If your package.json has something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

check for typos, and if `"scripts"` is in the root of your package.json, the same level as `version` and `name`.

---

If you installed CRA (create-react-app) globally with `npm install -g`, you may need to uninstall it and use `npx` instead. Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8086), or the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/):

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

Comment: my package.json has the scripts, but im not sure if my cd is correct

Answer (score -1):

I was able to reproduce the error behavior you described by cloning a react repo to my workstation and trying to start it before running `npm install`.  You may want to try running `npm i` in your project directory, and then try running `npm run start` once more.